# how to read from a text file and store in a separate array C# forms

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

I am having difficulting locating a piece of code that will successfully read a file and store the information in a separate array.

Someone has suggested

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("peter_testresults.txt");
```

in a past question but "var" is not recognized.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            //return a pass/fail
            //return number of correct answers
            //return number of incorrect answers
            //return index figures of incorrect values

    correctAnswers ={B,D,A,A,C,A,B,A,C,D,B,C,D,A,D,C,C,B,D,A} 


    private string determinePassOrFail (); //return a pass/fail


        string[] lines= File.ReadAllLines("peter_testresults.txt");

        var c = correctAnswers.Where((x, i) => x.Equals(lines[i])).Count();





     private int numberCorrectAnswers(); //return number of correct answers
        {

        }


    private int numberIncorrectAnswers(); //return number of incorrect answers

    {

    }

    private string questionsIncorrectAnswers(); //return index figures of incorrect
  values

    {

    }





    }
            }
```

Comment: what version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: Instead of `var lines = File.ReadAllLines("peter_testresults.txt");` does `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("peter_testresults.txt");` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't use `var` [(implicitly typed local variables)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) then that suggests you're using a C# 2 compiler (e.g. VS2005), and therefore almost certainly .NET 2. (I'm assuming you're *not* stuck with C# 1...)

Alternatively, you could be trying to use this as a field:

```
class Foo
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("...");
}
```

That won't work as fields can't be implicitly typed - but I'd argue that doing that IO in a field initializer is a bad idea anyway...

This should still work though:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("peter_testresults.txt");
```

as [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) was first introduced in .NET 2.

As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise you to try to upgrade to a more modern version of C#...

Comment: Currently operating on Visual Studio 2012. 

Does lines become the "stored array"?

Comment: @KerryG: If you're using VS 2012, then you need to give us more information about what you mean by "var is not recognized". A short but complete program, including the exact error message, would be useful. It's not clear what you mean by "stored array", but `lines` is a string array variable, the contents of which would be the lines in the file at the time it was loaded. (Changing the contents of the array doesn't change the file, or vice versa.)